# Ubuntu not booting properly with GTX 970

Tags: 14.04, boot, drivers, nvidia

I'm having a problem with booting into Ubuntu 14.04 through my GTX 970 graphics card. I had installed it previously onto my system along with the NVIDIA driver and it was working fine for the most part despite some hiccups but I recently tried to update some drivers but it didn't update correctly. I can't boot correctly anymore; all I get is either a black screen or a a screen with a text blinker on it (the proper name for it escapes me at the moment). I can get to the GRUB menu sometimes and have tried to update but get the errors shown here: [errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSXpX.jpg). Entering through recovery mode can get me to the login screen but trying to login just brings me back to the login screen! I don't have much experience in fixing Ubuntu in this way so please help if you can. I have tried other solutions but they haven't seemed to work for me.

Comment: login loop: http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop

Comment: I tried all of these solutions and nothing worked. Is there any other post that might apply to my issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for a while with my GTX 970 and I fixed it by using the boot-repair.

First you need to somehow get the ubuntu to boot in recovery mode. If that doesn't work try logging into the shell by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F3

Once you log in, then you should run boot repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

For some reason, everytime I use the GTX 970 driver to run my monitors, I had to do boot-repair...

Comment: I installed boot-repair but trying to use it gives me: Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display

Comment: can you in any way login to recovery mode without using shell? I had the exact same problem and it took me a day to fix it. I think I tried to login to recovery mode again and again and used boot-repair to finally fix it. Just bear with me and try to login with recovery mode.

Comment: Unfortunately, I ended up having to resort with the nuclear option and completely reinstalled Ubuntu since nothing was working (was not able to do TNT's method since I did it before it was posted). If this occurs again, I'll be sure to try this again and see what happens.

Comment: After you install your GTX970 driver, don't forget to do ubuntu boot repair!

Answer (score 0):

I had virtually the same problem on the same system: Ubuntu 14.04 with GTX 970.

I had installed the NVIDIA drivers from the website. What worked for me in the end was:

1. Go to recovery mode (graphics fail safe mode)
2. Enter Terminal (Ctrl+ALT+F1)
3. `sudo stop lightdm`  (or was it:   `sudo service lightdm stop`  )
4. Run the original installer file

   sudo NVIDIA.your version here.run --update

Note: it seems like a flaky and bothersome solution considering this appears to be a [common problem](http://choorucode.com/2013/02/07/how-to-fix-nvidia-driver-failure-on-ubuntu/). However, just uninstalling the driver with the script didn't fix my problem (maybe I forgot to stop lightdm beforehand?).
If it works for you, I suggest uninstalling and switching to the open drivers by installing

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates nvidia-settings-updates
```

(not sure where I saw that)

Answer (score -1):

I just turn off secure boot in the BIOS.

Comment: Please edit your answer to include more details, or else it should have been a comment.